# Excel SUMPRODUCT between table-row and table-column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have two tables and want to take a row of one and a column of the other as two arrays, then multiply first with first, second with second... and sum up all those products.

This is what I got:

`=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Rezepte; MATCH([@Cocktail]; Rezepte[Cocktail]); 1; 1; 36); OFFSET(Zutaten; 0; 1; 36; 1))`

As you can see I try to take arrays from my tables using OFFSET and calculate my answer using SUMPRODUCT

It returns *"A value in this formula is the wrong data type"*, however when I put the either one of the inner OFFSET functions twice instead of the other one, it works just as intended. So there seems to be some incompatibility there.

The first table contains recipes for cocktails, each cocktail has a row of values for the measures of all ingredients. The second table lists all ingredients and what their price per liter is (currently dummy values). I want to multiply the measures with the prices and add the values to calculate the price for each cocktail. *I know, it's kind of an odd use case :)*

And here is what the tables look like:

[Table one, of which I want to take one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtL99.png)

[Table two, of which I want to take one column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6AnV.png)

[Table three, in which I want the answer to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Riy.png)

Answer (score 1):

When using `SUMPRODUCT()` on a row and column, I use `TRANSPOSE()`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:C1,TRANSPOSE(E3:E5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this, however it did not work for me. I just now created a sheet with the exact same formula as you are showing and it is returning the same value error. There seems to be something wrong with the TRANSPOSE function.